# que error puede tener el siquiente codigo de procedimiento en mysql , quiero hacer un int ,out para retornar valores

Tags: mysql, oracle

código completo del script de procedimiento en mysql , quiero hacer un int ,out para retornar valores. El procedimiento es el siguiente.

```
DELIMITER $$
    Begin
        DECLARE v_constante INT ; 
        DECLARE id_categoria INT(10) ; 
        DECLARE nombre_pieza VARCHAR(30),
        DECLARE cantidad_piezas INT(10) ;
        DECLARE tiempo_promedio INT(10) ; 
        DECLARE precio_unidad float(5, 2) ;
        DECLARE id_equipo INT(10) ; 
        DECLARE c_total float(6,4);
    
        declare exit_loop boolean default false;
        declare  cursor1 cursor for select                                          id_categoria,nombre_pieza,cantidad_piezas,tiempo_promedio,precio_unidad,id_quipo     from piezas desgaste when id_equipo=p_id_equipo;
        declare continue handler for not found set exit_loop = True;
        open cursor1;
        cursor1_loop: loop
            fetch from cursor1 into     id_categoria,nombre_pieza,cantidad_piezas,tiempo_promedio,precio_unidad,id_quipo ;
            if exit_loop then
                leave
            end if ;
            c_total = precio_unidad(cantidad_piezas);
            SELECT nombre_pieza,cantidad_piezas,precio_unidad,c_total;                
        end loop cursor1_loop;
        close cursor1;        
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Fin del procedimiento

Comment: Bienvenido Gaspar Gonzalez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Si bien mySql ahora es de Oracle, lo que he visto es que este foro está más orientado a preguntas sobre la base de datos relacional Oracle.

Comment: Debes crear el procedimiento antes de poner el begin algo si ``create procedure nombre_procedimiento (IN variable Tipo)``de hecho esta estructura son cursores yo estoy dando eso ahora y donde pone ``declare  cursor1 cursor for select`` debes añadir la consulta la cual luego lo leerá con el fetch, luego por la tarde me conecto y te hecho una mano, lo que si necesito para ayudarte mejor que añadas tus tablas creadas  con tus insert para ayudarte mejor

Comment: sin lo que te he pedido no puedo ayudarte